# “On the Guardian” or “from the Guardian”

Tags: prepositions

Which is the appropriate preposition for this case?

> I am reading an article on the Guardian

Vs

> I am reading an article from the Guardian

Or should I use another preposition?

Comment: Assuming you mean the newspaper, it's usually _in_, but _from_ is possible.

Comment: Even if it's the website, I'd use **from**, unless you explicitly reference the website: "I am reading an article **on the Guardian homepage**."

Comment: Forget the preposition entirely - *I'm reading **a Guardian article***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since "the Guardian" can mean both a newspaper and the associated web site, either "on" or "from" might be used. One would say "in" to mean one was reading it in the actual newspaper, and "on" to indicate the web site. "from" works well in either case, and since the article would be the same in either case, is perhaps best. Using "on" emphasizes that the reader is viewing it on the actual site, and not, say, on some other site that quotes or reprints it.